# Multiples instances of Slideshow breaks code

Tags: javascript, slideshow, onmousemove

Having an issue, when I create multiple instances of this slideshow only one instance seems to work. Not sure how to reformat it so it works for multiple instances.

JAVASCRIPT

```
//SLIDESHOW
const slideshow = document.querySelector("section.slideshow")
const images = slideshow.querySelectorAll("img")

slideshow.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
const x = event.offsetX
const width = this.offsetWidth
const percentage = x / width
const imageNumber = Math.floor(percentage * images.length)

images.forEach(image => {
    image.style.zIndex = 0
})

images[imageNumber].style.zIndex = 1

})
```

HTML

```
<section class ="slideshow">
    <img src="assets/images/1.png">
    <img src="assets/images/3.png">
    <img src="assets/images/2.png">
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector("section.slideshow")` will always select the first `<section class="slideshow">` element it encounters.

If you want the same code to be able to handle multiple slideshow elements, you would need to select all of them into a `NodeList` and run the initialisation code for each instance.

Should go something like this: (not tested)

```
const slideshow_instances = document.querySelectorAll("section.slideshow")

for (var i = 0; i < slideshow_instances.length; i++) {
    const slideshow = slideshow_instances[i];
    const images = slideshow.querySelectorAll("img")

    slideshow.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    const x = event.offsetX
    const width = this.offsetWidth
    const percentage = x / width
    const imageNumber = Math.floor(percentage * images.length)

    images.forEach(image => {
        image.style.zIndex = 0
    })

    images[imageNumber].style.zIndex = 1

    })
}
```

Comment: @user3291787 Then you should accept it as an answer for your question.